# best data type for SHA256 hash

Tags: solidity, data-types

I'm trying to find a better data type for storing SHA256 hash, right now I'm using string, and I'm thinking of switching to byte32 but considering it I don't know if this is really a step in the right direction.  Is there a better data type for storing a sha256 hash?

This sha hash is not generated by sha256() so there is not a 0x prefix already affixed to it which is why I am concerned about adding those extra bytes instead of just leaving it as a string

Answer (score 1):

Use `bytes32`.

> not generated by sha256() so there is not a 0x prefix.

You didn't say where it comes from. I'll assume from outside the contract. Use a `bytes32` function argument to receive it. Formatting the input correctly will be a client-side concern.

Hope it helps.